# External Like button for Fan Page not showing up for user not logged to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I was trying to add FB Like on our Main Web site but linked (and thus showing likes for) to our Fan Page on FB. At first everything looked ok, but after few days magic started to happen. Button started to disappear every now and then... (other likes on product pages worked fine all the time).

I digged through the net. It looked like lots of people had problems with this. Firstly I found that I missed mysterious 'Step 2' in button generator (obvious flaw in dev FB UX - like ATM giving money in the first place, then Your card). Added og's meta data to my site. Still nothing.

I double and triple checked everything. All seemed ok. Eventually I pinned down the problem a bit. FB Like was always showing up when I was logged in to FB, but was disappearing only when I was logged out (but not always). But today even FB Like Generator stopped showing button for my Fan Page. I could enter URL for any page in the Internet and it was ok, but when I entered URL of my Fan page - button was just disappearing... soo frustrating.

I gave up and started to write this question to You and then it got me! Found the solution! Sometimes its good to sum up all of the facts :] Im leaving this Question for others wanderers of FB's og.

Just for fun - please post Your answers before I post the solution. I wonder if it's only me or it would be puzzle for most of You :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with Fan Page Country Restrictions settings. Admin restricted this Fan Page to be visible only for certain countries because of spamming bots eating ads budget. My country (Poland) was included in that list so when I was logged in, FB knew that I am from Poland and showed button. When I was logged out FB picked nearest server location or something as my default location which wasn't on the Restricted Country List and filtered out Like Button. Uhh...

The worst thing is FB doesn't provide any console output saying that 'You don't have permission to see this page'.

Ahh. The solution - remove Country Restrictions. Use black list instead of whitelist ;]