# Facebook Like Button not shown when not being logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have the following problem: I created via [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) a facebook like button to my fanpage.

Now the problem is that when I log out of facebook the button is not shown on my website.

I checked all the restrictions like [age](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440248/1331671) or [country](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14689656/1331671). I allow everything.

Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stupid one! I finally got it!

**My fanpage was still set to hidden. When I change the visibility the like button is shown.**